# How can i set css_dir relative to sass_dir directive in compass config?

Tags: config, compass-sass, sass

anyone know how and if possible to set in compass config, the css_dir directive set to be relative to the sass_dir, this for ensure that you can have relative path on dynamic paths.

exemple my dir structure are:

-> resources -> stylesheets -> scss

i want that the css file will be generated in:

-> resources -> stylesheets

here my code

```
http_path = "/"
sass_dir = "/"
css_dir = "../"
images_dir = ""
http_images_path = "#{http_path}"
javascripts_dir = ""
relative_assets = true
line_comments = false
sass_options = {:cache_location => ".compass-cache"}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible and if its not file a bug on compass and one of us will look into what is going on. The compass compile / watch command should only be looking for `.s(a|c)ss` files so I don't see why this wouldn't work and if it doesn't its possibly a bug